# Does $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k)-\cos(k+1)}{k}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was given the following series and I'm asked to decide (and prove) whether it converges or diverge:

$\displaystyle\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k)-\cos(k+1)}{k}$

So far, I couldn't successfully approach the solution. At least, I've tried to use series expansion for $\cos$ and then received

$$\displaystyle\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k)-\cos(k+1)}{k} = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\cdot k^{2n}-(-1)^n\cdot(k+1)^{2n}}{2n!}}{k} =$$
$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{0}{k}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^n\cdot k^{2n}-(-1)^n\cdot(k+1)^{2n}}{2n!}}{k} = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\cdot k^{2n}-(-1)^n\cdot(k+1)^{2n}}{2n!}}{k}$$

Can someone give me a hint to go on or can provide a different type of a possible approach to the solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect this will work: susbstitute $\cos(k) = \tfrac{e^{ik}+e^{-ik}}{2}$,  $\cos(k+1) = \tfrac{e^{i(k+1)}+e^{-i(k+1)}}{2}$ and $\tfrac{1}{k} = \int_{0}^{1}x^k\,dx$, then interchange the order of the summation and the integral, use the formula for the sum of a geometric series, then evaluate the resulting integral. Note: Justifying the change of the order of the sum and integral is tricky. You might need to do the above with the sum of the first $N$ terms, and then let $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Please, learn about Dirichlet's criterion,

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Good idea. Since convergence is all that is needed, [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've got it :)

Answer (score 4):

One does not need to appeal to Dirichlet's test or resort to calculus to determine convergence.  Rather, we simply note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\cos(k)-\cos(k+1)}{k}&=\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\cos(k)}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\cos(k+1)}{k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\cos(k)}{k}-\sum_{k=2}^{K+1} \frac{\cos(k)}{k-1}\\\\
&=\cos(1)-\sum_{k=2}^K \frac{\cos(k)}{k(k-1)}-\frac{\cos(K+1)}{K}\tag1
\end{align}$$

The second term on the right-hand side of $(1)$ converges as the denominator is $O(1/k^2)$ (in fact, the sum is bounded in absolute value by $1$) and the third term tends to $0$ as $K\to\infty$.  Hence, the series converges as was to be shown!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**- $\operatorname{cos}(k)-\operatorname{cos}(k+1)=2\operatorname{sin}\frac{2k+1}{2}\operatorname{sin}\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

This is not what was asked for in the question, but it is interesting enough that I thought I would post an answer about it.

Let's write the first few terms. $$\cos(1)-\cos(2)+\frac{\cos(2)}{2}-\frac{\cos(3)}{2}+\frac{\cos(3)}{3}-\frac{\cos(4)}{3}+...$$
Let $a_n$ be the coefficient in front of $\cos(n)$. So then our sum is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n\cos(n)}$$
We can see that $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1+\frac{1}{2}$, $a_3=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3},...$

And in general, $a_n=\frac{-1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \neq1$ and with $a_1=1.$ This sum can be thought of a Fourier series of *some function* $f$ with a period of $2\pi$ evaluated at $x=1$ with satisfying $a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x=0$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)\mathrm{d}x=0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. I think it would be very interesting if someone could find such a function $f$.